# Cannot Login After Drupal 7 migration

Tags: 7, users

```
Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?
```

The error above shows even though I have inputted correct credentials in my site(192.168.5.141/doc_monitor). Below are the steps I have tried to solve my problem.

1. Reset my password in Drupal users table using md5 hash.
2. Verify mod_rewrite is enabled. mod_rewrite module is loaded as I can view it in phpinfo()
3. Verify RewriteBase rule in my .htaccess

   RewriteBase /doc_monitor
4. Repair/Truncate sesssions table.
5. Set (doc_monitor)drupal files to 777 permission.
6. Run update.php
7. Clear browser cache and drupal table cache;
8. Truncate flood table.

I always restarted my Apache in every changes I made. Anymore suggestions? I dont know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 4):

First thing to do to see if the login is functioning is use `drush uli`, which will create a login link for user 1. If that works, after logging in, set your password to test123. Logout, then try to log in with that.

You can also set the password with drush, trying to edit the md5 hash etc is not reliable.

https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-password/

This doesn't have anything to do with the files directory.

Another thing to do is check your settings file just to ensure you are talking to the right database. Also check the database to see if the user you are logging in as is not blocked (status).

If you had previously set cookie domain in the settings file, verify that the value is correct.